# TFS 2010 collections to TFS 2012 without interruption

Tags: team-foundation-server

I need to migrate several (50+) team project collections currently hosted on TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. The current installation must be running so that the teams still can check in work items.

I haven't been able to find a detailed guidance on how to COPY the team project collection to the TFS 2012 server without having to detach the collections in TFS 2010.

Can someone provide a detailed guidance how to accomplish this?

Comment: 50 team project collections? are you sure you didn't mean Team projects?

Comment: Yeah I ment 50 project collections :)

Comment: Goodness, i'd hate to manage the build/test controllers for that!

Comment: What is the longest acceptable downtime? Minutes? Hours?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out of the box, however the TFS ALM rangers have released a tool called the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)  which can synchronize between 2 different servers.

Willy Schuab has a great introduction series - [TFS Integration Tools Where does one start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/11/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-1.aspx), [Part 1b](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/09/01/where-does-one-start-part-1b-pre-requisites.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/13/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-2-try-a-simple-migration.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/17/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-3-dust-has-settled-did-it-work.aspx), [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/18/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-4-mapping-users-the-easy-way.aspx)

Also a [list of related links and guides](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/10/07/tfs-integration-platform-summary-of-links.aspx)

> **Limitations**
>
> As mentioned above, there are items that are not migrated when using the tool and this should to be taken into consideration when deciding on whether to do a migration or upgrade.
>
> *What IS NOT migrated by the Toolkit*
>
> - Check-in notes
> - Labels
> - Permissions
> - Workspaces
> - Pending Changes
> - Shelvesets
> - File encodings
> - Subscriptions
> - Test Cases
> - Check-in policies
> - Reports
> - Team Portal / SharePoint
> - Process Templates
> - Work item queries
> - Builds
> - Warehouse data

Comment: This is not sufficient for my task. I need to preserve as much as possible from the team projects on TFS 2010.

Comment: @OliverNilsen that's fine, but it's the only way to have no downtime.  If you need to preserve everythign you'll need some downtime per team project collection.  However you can migrate them one by one if you need.

Comment: When you say migrate, do you mean move the projects one by one to the TFS 2012? If so, I must not move anything. The TFS 2010 must be running all the time. My only option is to copy somehow. But I could use a more detailed process. The ones I find, always mentions detaching the collection on the server. Can this be done somehow without detaching?

Comment: No, what you're asking for is not possible.

Comment: Actually, it may be possible to do a normal upgrade by reattaching the team project collection databases, then using TFS Integration Platform to sync any changes that have occurred since then.  Then only the new history will have incorrect date/times but they shouldn't be more than a few hours out if you perform the upgrade fast enough.